# How to create and use a moralis server in the newer version to listen to events?

Tags: solidity, events, nodejs, moralis, vercel

I am following the blockchain tutorial by Patrick Collins. For the NFT Marketplace frontend, to listen to the events emitted, moralis server is to be used.

[This is the video with the required timestamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ&t=91221s)

But the server dashboard in admin.moralis.io which has been used in the tutorial has been deprecated. I have been trying to follow the official docs and videos for migrating to the new one, but unable to understand and do it.

I am confused whether just running the demo code locally for server given in https://docs.moralis.io/docs/nodejs-demo-parse-server-migration is enough, or do I have to host it somewhere and also if I have to create a stream, which is being shown in the new dashboard of admin.moralis.io, so that I can listen to the onchain events?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you will need to [self-host your Moralis server](https://docs.moralis.io/docs/self-hosted-moralis-server) and use the [Streams API](https://docs.moralis.io/docs/set-up-streams-with-parse-server) as an alternative to syncing events as shown in that tutorial.